# How are non-tail comments getting edited after five minutes?

Tags: discussion, comment-edits

I thought maybe I was imagining it before, but now I'm *almost certain* I have seen a comment edited *in-place* after five minutes.  The second comment to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/251687/67775), made by a Trusted User, had passed the 5-minute mark.  I posted a third comment.  I came back a few minutes later to read a fourth comment and the second comment had an additional sentence but still bore its original time-stamp (preceding my third comment by 12 minutes)!

Is this a Trusted User privilege?  Or is there a hack I don't know about?  (Just wink if it's a secret and maybe passively mention what the magic threshold on SE is to be initiated into such secrets ;)

Answer (score 8):

That comment was last edited 1 minute and 8 seconds shy of the 5 minute mark - 3 minutes and 52 seconds after being posted.

Perhaps you just missed seeing the edit?

Comment: Yes, I was hedging my question because I'm not sure how aggressively comment edits are pushed.  Maybe to definitively close the question could you describe or point to what the current content update push policies/implementations are?  (E.g., things like, "This question as a new answer," or, "This answer has been edited," or, "There is a new comment."  Don't think I've ever seen "There is an edit to an existing comment"....)

Comment: @feetwet Indeed, there is no such notification for comment edits. You have to refresh the page to see them.

Comment: You *should've* seen the edited comment after you posted your own, @feetwet - normally, the entire thread is refreshed then. The only exception I can think of off-hand is the mobile app, which does not.

Comment: Right, that's what I expected, but after posting my own the prior comment did not reflect the change that, per the edit timeline, had been made.  I'm using current desktop Chrome, not mobile.  I guess at worst this comes down to a minor bug.  Should I retag as such or just close?

Comment: Unless you can figure out how to reproduce this, there's not a lot I can do with it. I did check the logs; all edits were submitted in under 5 minutes.

Comment: If you want we could retry the steps -- you post a comment, I load the page, you edit your comment, I add a comment, then see what comes back.  If you think that would be valuable how should we arrange the debug session?